# Php SQLSRV query timeout or login timeout

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3.1 and connect to remote a mssql database. But sometimes mssql connect take long time and i want to set a query time out or mssql connect login time out. But seems it doesn't work for me.
what i may have missed?

My connect configuration;

```
try{
  $dsn ="sqlsrv:Server=IP,Port;Database=DB;";
  $db  = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password");

 //$db->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, 3);
 //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  $query=('select * from Accounting');

  $cmd = $db->prepare($query,array(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT => 1 ));

  if(!$cmd->execute()){
    throw new PDOException ($cmd->errorInfo());
  }
  return $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  die("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

**Edit:** I'm using this drive;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdo-sqlsrv-driver-reference?view=sql-server-ver15

I create a loop sending query to db;

```
Name    Status  Type    Size        Time       Respose
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
test    200      xhr    608kb      1.16ms      login time out
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
test    200      xhr    618kb      39.45s      gives TCP error
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
test    200      xhr    10.5kb     400ms       working well
```

**First time login timeout working but second time doesn't**

Comment: Your script seems correct, but these links may give you additional information: [PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT not work](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/838) and [Idle Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-resiliency?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Zhorov thanks for answer i looked that and it seems support only mssql 2014 and above but i use sql version 2008(SP2)

Answer (score 0):

The desired parameter is `LoginTimeout`, which takes a number of seconds, and it's passed in the DSN:

```
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=IP,Port;Database=DB;LoginTimeout=5;';
$db = new \PDO($dsn, 'username', 'password');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

The default timeout is 15 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a timeout on connection, not on a query. The timeout can be set in connection string:

```
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=IP,Port;Database=DB;Connect Timeout=30";
```

[Connection parameters](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/)

Comment: An invalid keyword 'Connect Timeout' was specified in the DSN string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-setattribute?view=sql-server-ver15    attributes in there